# result is not displayed in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

![enter image description here][1]

I was trying to make a program for calculator by watching online tutorial, I hope my codes are correct but I am not able to display the answers (result). Only the result is not displayed.

Comment: Pease do not post images.  rather copy/paste the data as text, directly into your question

Comment: I didn't know about that . point noted